# Bulk insert Format file error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I write this bulk insert format file:

```
8.0
7
1       SQLCHAR       1       9       " "      1     f1           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR       1       5       "           "     2     f2        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       1       12     " "      3     f3         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR       1       10     " "     4     f4         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR       1       8     "   "   5     f5         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR       1       5     "   "   6     f6         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR       1       5     "\n"   7     f7         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

and my file data is:

```
43266200 6827           43295200 1393/05/23 14:26:26     18      1
43266200 6819           43295200 1393/05/23 14:28:45    113      1
```

But when i run this query:

```
bulk insert goy
from 'd:\test.txt'
with(
    formatfile='d:\format.fmt'
);
```

sql server error is:

```
Msg 4862, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "d:\format.fmt" is incomplete or could not be read. Operating system error code (null).
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8270755/1080354

Comment: Your data shows seven columns but your format file only defines six.  That's probably what it means by "the file "d:\format.fmt" is incomplete"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new line at the end of the fmt file. then save. it will work