# Bulk import into Azure

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, bulkinsert

For a Bulk Insert, I have got a data file and a format file (xml);

- File.dat
- File.xml

This is working OnPremises with a Bulk Insert statement, however in Azure it seems to have a problem with the format file. Below are the steps I have taken

---

**Set Storage Access**

- Created a Shared Access Signature
- Set the container Access Policy to 'Blob (anonymous read access for blobs only)

**Create an Database Scoped Credential to the Storage**

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL StorageCredential
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'This is my secret' (Shared Access Signature Key)
```

**Create an external Data Source**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE Storage
WITH  (
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'https://<storagename>.blob.core.windows.net/<containername>', 
    CREDENTIAL = StorageCredential
);
```

**File Query (Bulk insert or Openrowset)**

```
BULK INSERT <Schema>.<Table>
FROM 'File.dat'
WITH (
    DATA_SOURCE = 'Storage',
    FORMATFILE = 'File.xml'
)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'File.dat',
    DATA_SOURCE = 'Storage',
    FORMATFILE =  'File.xml'
) AS DataFile;
```

They are both not working with the error;

'Cannot bulk load because the file is inclomplete or could not be read'

However if I can succesfully run the following query;

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'File.xml', 
    DATA_SOURCE = 'Storage',
    SINGLE_NClob) AS DataFile
```

Comment: Does this help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229989/bulk-insert-w-fmt-file-operating-system-error-code-null

Comment: @TheGameiswar Thank you, but I am using XML (And already saw that post and tried with the XML file!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the answer and I will post it myself (In case other people also run into this problem).

The datasource of the format file should be specified individually. I tried the way specified in the documentation of Microsoft; [Bulk Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql)

However there is an error in the parameter name. It states that the correct parameter is 'FORMATFILE_DATASOURCE', however it should be 'FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE'. (This is commented at the bottom)

```
BULK INSERT <Schema>.<Table>
FROM 'File.dat'
WITH (
    DATA_SOURCE = 'Storage',
    FORMATFILE = 'File.xml',
    FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'Storage'
)
```